# Package minitoc Warning: W0010 No file output.toc. NINITOCS NOT PREPARED

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I'm writing a latex document and I would like to add a table of contents. I have used the following code:

```
%%%%% MINI TABLES
        \dominitoc % include a mini table of contents
%\dominilof  % include a mini list of figures
%\dominilot  % include a mini list of tables
% This aligns the bottom of the text of each page.  It generally makes things look better.
        \flushbottom
% This is where the whole-document ToC appears:
        {
        \setlength{\baselineskip}{1.1\frontmatterbaselineskip}
        \hypersetup{linkcolor=GREYDARK}
        \tableofcontents
        \listoffigures
        \mtcaddchapter
        \listoftables
        \mtcaddchapter
        }
        {
        \setlength{\baselineskip}{1.1\frontmatterbaselineskip}
        \input{sections/glossary}
        }

    \end{romanpages}
```

But when I compile, I get an empty table of contents and table of figures that looks like this:

[image]

I do not understand what is happening, the only log message I get is the following (in yellow):

[image]

Does someone know how to fix this please?

Comment: Just to double check, have you compiled twice?  (Also, you don't need minitoc for a traditional table of contents.  Minitoc is for when you want a per-chapter table of contents, or something similar.)

Comment: yes I compiled twice and I know that minitoc is for small chapter table content I want them to appear as well.